# Chrome WebSQL select doesn't return any data, when there is data in the sqlite db

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, extjs4, web-sql

I have a table in my sqlite db (accessed in my web app via websql) called `Parameter` and it has 79 rows in it when I access it via the command line:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from Parameter;
79
```

However, when I debug through my ExtJS WebSQL app and see the results of it running

```
select * from Parameter;
```

it gets nothing. I've debugged to know that it's not an ExtJS problem, where it might not be processing the websql results properly. The websql results have no records.

Any ideas on how to debug more in-depth into Chrome WebSQL to know why this is happening? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Check the log of sqlite db (both error log and query log).

Comment: @XupyprMV how do I do that? In `sqlite3` on the command line?